# onBackPressed() not calling new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, onbackpressed

There is 2 activities in my project. I want to call a new activity when press the back button. I tried both onBackPressed(),onKeyDown() for that. My code is given below. I searched for this in google but nothing worked for me.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("update", is_updated.toString());
        if(is_updated){
            Intent i = new Intent(ProductDetailsActivity.this,ProductListActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            is_updated = false;
        }else {
            finish();
        }
    }
```

I logged the value "is_update", even the value is "true" Its not calling the ProductListActivity.class, The same code is working for button click.How I can call the new activity in onBackpressed(), Can anyone help me.

Comment: why do you want to start a new activity. Back button is suppose to take you to previous activity

Comment: I know that, I want to update some data's in previous activity

Comment: then use `startActivityForResult`

Comment: The "ProductDetailsActivity" updated data to server.  I want to start ProductListActivity.class again. Then only the list get update.

Comment: Really Sorry guys actually I have to call the AsyncTask before to update data in server and on Postexcecute call the Intent. I am so sorry for the mistake and wasting your time.

Answer (score 1):

as @Raghunandan said. Here I am explaining his words. If you want to update data in previous `activity` you should use `startActivityForResult` for this you call `finish()` and `override finish()` and use `setResult(RESULT_OK)` like:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("update", is_updated.toString());
        if(is_updated){

            finish();
            is_updated = false;
        }
    }

@Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();

       Intent intent = new Intent();
       intent.putExtra("updated_data", "data");//set whatever your updated data is
       setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    }
```

Now back to the previous `activity` override `onActivityResult` method. I suppose you are aware of `onActivityResult` method and its usage, if not read it from [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Hope you will get the desired results.

Comment: I dont want the data from that activity, If any update in the second activity(to server), I want to restart the 1st activity on back button press.

Comment: But i mentioned,I want to start a new activity in onbackpressed()

Comment: `start a new activity in onbackpressed()`..Where is server mentioned in this?? Clear your question first...

Comment: As i mentioned in the question I just want to restart an Activity when press back button. There is nothing related to server. I want to restart or start an activity when i press back button.